# eCommerce opensource plattforms

Tags: open-source, ecommerce

I'm currently working on a project aimed to contribute to eCommerce and I'd like to make a list with different eCommerce, opensource plattforms, in order to integrate with them.

The requirements are:

- It needs to be opensource, because I need to develop modules to integrate my product.
- It needs to provide REST services support underneath.
- Any language/technology, no matter if it's standalone desktop app or web CMS...

I've found couple examples on the net (such as Magento) but I'd like to know if there's any more and, if it's possible (but not required) that it could be integrated both on physical Points of Sale and web.

Comment: Related Meta discussion: [Asking for software to integrate with or make your own tool compatible to](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2517/60)

Answer (score 4):

I work at [Broadleaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org).    The community version is Apache 2 open source and runs on the Java/Spring stack.

If you want to narrow your choices by stack, the following is a good start:

- Java - [Broadleaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org)
- PHP - [Magento](http://magento.com/)
- Ruby - [Spree](https://spreecommerce.com/)

If your needs are typical, you might want to consider a hosted solution like Shopify or BigCommerce.

Comment: I'd normally say this is way too minimal but given the question it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Commerce KickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which is a (popular) [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) "distribution", and which should fit most, if not all, of your requirements also. Some more details about it (from the linked page):

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). It includes the latest versions of Drupal core, Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on. It also gives you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search configuration, and a custom back office interface.

To be complete, there is also [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com), a SO-site dedicated to Drupal, which has tons of questions (and great answers) about topics such as [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and/or [Commerce KickStart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).